# How to create a panel like the MAC upgrade notification?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mu2sU.png)

Just like this, at the top-right corner, like the OS X upgrade notification. 
I tried NSAlert,cor NSPanel but failed. I want to know how to create it, Or it is not a system class?

Comment: Please **add more details.** What exactly have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

The class you are looking for is `NSUserNotification`, where you can set title and description of the notification before it is displayed.

Play a little with these options there to get them right for you.

BTW: there are two styles of `NSUserNotification` available. The simple ones and those with actions attached to them. Unfortunately you can only use one type per app as this value is set in your .plist file.

Here is some code I wrote some time ago to display error notifications through NSUserNotifactionCenter:

```
- (void)postErrorNotificationWithTitle:(NSString *)title subtitle (NSString*)subtitle description:(NSString *)description {
    NSUserNotification* userNoti = [[NSUserNotification alloc] init]; //create the notification with all its information
    userNoti.title = title;
    userNoti.subtitle = subtitle;
    userNoti.informativeText = description;
    NSBeep(); //create error sound

    [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] deliverNotification:userNoti]; //Add and remove the notification from the notification center, we only want to display it
    [[NSUserNotificationCenter defaultUserNotificationCenter] removeDeliveredNotification:userNoti];
}
```